# Tycho: How to bring all the eclipse test-plugins in target?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, surefire

We have the following setup for our product.
main feature - which will build and deploy to nexus.
test feature - which will build and installed locally.

We have test extension points in our test plugins. We use those extension points in our testing. The problem is tycho only brings the dependent plugins in target during test runtime(which misses out few test extension points), although I want all the test plugins to be there in the target.

Is there any solution for the problem I'm facing? I would like to build all the plugins first and then run the test cases with all the plugins in target. Current behaviour is once the test plugin is bulid, test is executed. Also, we dont want to deploy test plugins in nexus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the approaches mentioned in the below link ?
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform

I hope this will solve your issue.